# How to access another container in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a multi-container pod consisting on multiple interrelated microservices.  On docker-compose if I wanted to access the another container in a compose I just use the name of the service.

I am trying to do the same thing with Kube, without having to create a pod per microservice.

I tried the name of the container or suffix with `.local` neither worked and I got an UnknownHostException.

My preference is also to have all the microservices runnning on port 80, but in case that does not work within a single pod, I also tried having each microservice running on it's own port and use `localhost` but that didn't work either it simply said connection refused (as opposed to Unknown Host)

Comment: Containers within a pod share an IP address and port space, and can find each other via localhost. They can also communicate with each other using standard inter-process communications like SystemV semaphores or POSIX shared memory. Containers in different pods have distinct IP addresses and can not communicate by IPC. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/

Comment: That does not sound right because all my containers are running on port 80 they should be isolated right?

Comment: sure, in this case you need to create different pods for your services or change port on any container

Comment: So if everything is on one port it needs to be one pod per container.  Ok, I just tried to do it each container to be its own port.  Still does not work yet but at leats localhost resolves

Comment: if you have all the container in one POD. you should be able access using `localhost:port`

Comment: The first comment is spot-on. If one of your containers is exposing port 80, that would cause the others to not even bind at the same. Your options would be - binding to a different port, or using a separate pod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The applications in a pod all use the same network namespace (same IP and port space), and can thus “find” each other and communicate using localhost. Because of this, applications in a pod must coordinate their usage of ports.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#resource-sharing-and-communication